# GitHub Composite Actions: Can't find 'action.yml'

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to create a composite action on my repo as follows:

```bash
.github
├── actions
│   └── setup-composite.yml
└── workflows
    └── composite_test.yml
```

the content of the files is the bare minumum

```bash
# setup-composite.yml

name: setup-env

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: '3.9'

    - name: run dependencies
      shell: bash
      run: |
        pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and then I'm trying to reference the composite workflow using

```bash
# composite_test.yml

name: Composite Test
on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: composite
        uses: ./.github/actions/setup-composite
```

The contents of requirements.txt are just a couple of packages for testing purposes.

But when this workflow runs I get `Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/_actions/{profile}/{repo}/main/.github/actions/setup-composite'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?`

As far as I know I followed all the steps from the [Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action). I also looked at multiple other answers, including

- [Error in github action from usethis package Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190854/error-in-github-action-from-usethis-package-cant-find-action-yml-action-yam)
- [How can I reference other actions from my GitHub Action's action.yml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611841/how-can-i-reference-other-actions-from-my-github-actions-action-yml-file)
- [How can I reference other actions from my GitHub Action's action.yml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611841/how-can-i-reference-other-actions-from-my-github-actions-action-yml-file)

and multiple threads on the GitHub discussion board.

My repo is public. I tried several combinations of the `uses: ./.github/actions/setup-composite` statement, including referencing by branch, but I ran out of ideas to try.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Composite actions have to be defined with `action.yml`.

I have done something similar, try this layout:

```
.github
├── actions
│   └── setup-composite
│      └── action.yml
└── workflows
    └── composite_test.yml
```

Comment: I have my layout the same, and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Nevermind, I was not checking out the same repository as the workflow, before I tried using the path to my `actions` directory. See here for more: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-an-action-in-the-same-repository-as-the-workflow